# Percentage of completion of script: Name a file with percentage

Tags: linux, unix, ksh, percentage

I have a script that i run on 2k servers simultaneously that creates a temp working directory on a NAS.

The script builds a list of files...the list could be 1k files or 1m files.
I run a for loop on the list to run some grep commands on each file

```
counter=0
num_files=`wc -l $filelist`
cat $filelist| while read line; do
do_stuff_here
counter=`expr $counter+ 1`
((percent=$counter/$num_files))
##CREATE a file named "$percent".percent
done
```

What I am thinking is I can take the total number of files from the list ( wc -l $filelist) and add a counter that i increase by 1 in the loop.
I can then divide $counter/$num_files.

This seems to work, but the problem I have is that I would like to rename the same file, instead of just creating a new one each time. What can i do here?

I do not want this to output to stdout/stderr....i already have enough stuff going to these places. I would like to be able to browse to a subdir in WinSCP and quickly see where each is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
touch 0.percent 
counter=0 
num_files=$(wc -l $filelist)
num_files=${num_files/ */}
cat $filelist| while read line; do 
do_stuff_here 
mv -f {$((counter*100/num_files)),$((++counter*100/num_files))}.percent 
done 
rm -f *.percent
```